# Raffle tickets: buy random tickets or a numerically sequential block?

Tags: probability

I can't see a difference in probability of these two raffle ticket strategies - buy random tickets or a block - but maybe there is?

There are 10,000 tickets sold in a raffle. All the tickets are numbered 1 to 10,000. There is one drawing for the one ticket that will be the winner. I can buy multiple tickets to increase my odds of winning, so I want to buy 100; the cost of 100 tickets is less than the possible prize.

When buying 100 tickets, is there a difference in the probability of winning if

1) I buy 100 individual tickets that have randomly selected numbers, i.e., 27, 456, 6789, 9988, etc., up to a total of 100 tickets.

or

2) I buy one sequential block of tickets, i.e. numbered 5600-5699.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the drawing is truly random i.e., its probability distribution is uniform then it doesn't matter how you you buy you tickets. If it's not random, then how you buy the tickets matters.

As an example, say the tickets are characterized by a sequence of 5 digits and the digits are chosen randomly. If there is no correlation between chosen/drawn digits (between the digits in the same raffle and between the digits over different raffles) then the distribution is uniform and no matter how you buy the tickets you have the same chance.

Otherwise, by characterizing the drawing process and buying tickets accordingly you have a higher chance.

Comment: Thanks, the drawing is someone's hand going into a barrel of 10,000 tickets, so it's fairly random, but not a machine or computer-aided drawing.

Comment: You know, if we can't really characterize the randomness of the process or don't have the tools to do so then we should just assume it's really "random" ;)

Comment: True; I'm a math newbie :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference in the probabilities. You have made a mistake in (2) though, if you buy every ticket from 5600-5700, you will actually buy 101 tickets. If you buy 5600-5699 though, the probabilities will be equal.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense; and yes, I edited my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If I was buying 100 tickets, I would cover all of the first 2 digits by getting tickets 0001, 0100, 0200, 0300,... 9900 then I can "brag" that I at least matched the first 2 digits (which is almost true).  Imagine people that buy a block of 100 and the first digit mismatches that entire block.  Those are "dead" tickets already.  At least my way you have a chance (although no better chance to win).

Just take the winner first 2 numbers, and find a losing ticket with the correct last 2 numbers (assuming the winning ticket is exactly 4 digits which is 9000 of them I think), and splice them together before the real winner shows up then do as Pink Floyd says... Run like Hell! or as Steve Miller Band says "Take the money and run".  Better use a fake name too and move out of town.

By the way, check your wording.  You have buy 100 tickets and they you state up to 100 tickets.  That seems to be a contradiction.